# Using Method of Inherited Interface with Generic Repository Pattern, UnitOfWork in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

***My Problem is from here,***

---

I have written an Interface for country repository and I am following generic repository with UnitOfWork, I am also using ninject for DI

```
public interface ICountryRepository : IRepository<Country>
{
    List<Country> GetAll();
}
```

Implemented country repository interface,

```
public class CountryRepository : BaseRepository<Country>, ICountryRepository
{
    public CountryRepository(DbContextcontext) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public List<Country> GetAll(){
    // Not implemented
    }
}
```

There is a additional method in **ICountryRepository** interface and I have implemented it too. But when I need that method to use using UnitOfWork, I can't use that method. That is giving **System.NullReferenceException**

I have tried,

```
ICountryRepository repository = UnitOfWork.Repository<Country>() as ICountryRepository;
return repository.GetAll();
```

The downcasting suggest the method but *without* casting the method is not **accessible**.

Additional Codes are given,

### Entities

---

**Base Entity**

```
    public class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

**Product Entity**

```
public class Country : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Repositories

---

**Interface**

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
}
```

**Base Repository**

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    protected IDbContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> _dbEntitySet;
    private bool _disposed;

    public BaseRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbEntitySet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _context.SetAsAdded(entity);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed && disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

### Unit Of Work

---

**Interface**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;

    void BeginTransaction();

    int Commit();

    Task<int> CommitAsync();

    void Rollback();

    void Dispose(bool disposing);

}
```

**Unit of work implemented**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private bool _disposed;
    private Hashtable _repositories;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
        {
            _repositories = new Hashtable();
        }

        var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

        if (_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
        }

        var repositoryType = typeof(BaseRepository<>);

        _repositories.Add(type, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _context));

        return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
    }

   /* Other Implementation
    *
    *
    *
    */
}
```

Comment: It's probably in this line:  `_context.Set<TEntity>()`. Your're passing `BaseProduct` which is not an entity and then EF cannot create a `DBSet`. `UnitOfWork.Repository<Country>`should do fine, but `UnitOfWork.Repository<BaseProduct>` will not.

Comment: I have edited that, Unfortunately that is not the issue. I am still facing the issue @smoksnes

Comment: Nothing seems to implement `IBaseProductRepository` so your cast will always be null. Also, any particular reason for using `Activator`? There's nothing magic going on. You should be able to use `new BaseRepository<TEntity>(_context)`.

Comment: @smoksnes, I've changed that mistake. And I am using Ninject for Dependency Injection that is doing the magic. But The problem is not still solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You are resolving an instance of type `BaseRepository<Country>`, not an instance of type `CountryRepository`.

Comment: @Maarten Any possible solution/ resource ?

Comment: Now you're casting to `ICountryRepository`, but you're creating a `BaseRepository`. So the cast will still result in null.

Comment: `ICountryRepository` is NOT the same thing as `IRepository<Country>`. You cannot cast the latter to the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you are resolving an instance of type `BaseRepository<Country>`, not your derived `CountryRepository` class, which is the one you want to resolve in case of a `Country`.

One crude hard coded solution is to replace your generic-repository-type-to-resolve with a custom-type-to-resolve. Something like this. You will need to manually add entries to the dictionary.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> s_RepositorySuperTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type> {
    { typeof(BaseRepository<Country>), typeof(CountryRepository) }
};

public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity {
    if (_repositories == null) {
        _repositories = new Hashtable();
    }

    var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;
    if (_repositories.ContainsKey(type)) {
        return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
    }

    var closedRepositoryType = typeof(BaseRepository<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity));
    if (s_RepositorySuperTypes.ContainsKey(closedRepositoryType)) {
        closedRepositoryType = s_RepositorySuperTypes[closedRepositoryType];
    }
    _repositories.Add(type, Activator.CreateInstance(closedRepositoryType, _context));

    return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make your custom repository methods extension methods.

So if your extra method was called `GetCountriesByContinent` something like

```
public static class CountryRepository
{
    public static IEnumerable<Country> GetCountriesByContinent(this IRepository<Country> repo, string continent)
    {
        return repo.Where(c => c.Continent == continent);
    }
}
```

You should also look into covariance vs contravariance which may help you understand why you have this issue in the first place.